# How can I tell who created a link to a SharePoint document?

Tags: sharepoint-online, links, sharing

Users are not sharing links to docs/folders properly.  Instead of selecting 'users with existing access' or 'view only' access when sharing a link, they're leaving the default of Edit, giving whoever has that link Edit privileges.

Where can I see who is creating the link (not who accessed the link)?

Comment: Did you try following the steps given in [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-sharing-auditing)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Office 365 Security & Compliance](https://protection.office.com/unifiedauditlog) page with global admin> Audit log search> Under Activities, click **Sharing and access request activities** to search for **Created sharing invitation** to check who created the sharing link:

[image]

[image]

More information:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-sharing-auditing?view=o365-worldwide#step-1-search-for-sharing-events-and-export-the-results-to-a-csv-file